# AngularJS: Load dropdown Selected from model

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, select

I have a page where I need to set the option in a dropdown to a value from my model. I am trying to populate the existing selected option (made when the record was created).

```
<select name="assemblyOptions" 
        ng-model="model.edit.assembly" 
        ng-options="option as option.name for option in assemblyOptions">
</select>
```

This is how the code looked when I created the record. "assemblyOptions" is an object in scope that has the options to display.

When one is selected it is written to the `$scope.model.edit.assembly` of which "name" is the item displayed (hence "option as option.name for" ...).

Now, I am on a different page and I have the model data including the model.edit.assembly object.

I want the dropdown to be set to the value in the model.

I have tried using the `ng-selected` directive but can't get the syntax right.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: I found it. Add "track by" at the end of the ng-options. In my case it was : ng-options="option as option.name for option in assemblyOptions track by option.name"

Answer (score 0):

You can use track by to make the options unique

```
<select name="assemblyOptions" 
        ng-model="model.edit.assembly" 
        ng-options="option as option.name for option in assemblyOptions track by option.name">
</select>
```

Comment: i did not see the answer comment